XSLT looping over nested data
I have nested xml data. I am looping over item element and would like to get total sum of the price of all items using recursion.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
  <item>
    <name>Product A</name>
    <price>10.00</price>
    <item>
      <name>Product B</name>
      <price>5.00</price>
      <item>
        <name>Sub-Product 1</name>
        <price>2.00</price>
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <price>2.00</price>
  </item>
</order>

I see that the last item element is not considered while looping. I am not sure what I am missing.
`<!-- Recursive template to calculate the sum of prices -->
  <xsl:template name="sumPrices">
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum"/>

    <!-- Iterate over each item -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$items">
      <!-- Add the price of the current item to the sum -->
      <xsl:variable name="currentPrice" select="number($items/price)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="newSum" select="$sum + $currentPrice"/>
      <!-- Recursive call for sub-items -->
      <xsl:call-template name="sumPrices">
        <xsl:with-param name="items" select="item"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$newSum"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Output the total sum -->
    <xsl:if test="not($items)">
      <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
      </total>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>



I am not sure what I am missing.

Hard to say what you're missing when you're not showing us the initial call of the template, so that we are unable to reproduce your problem.
In any case, there is no need for recursion. You can use simply:
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//item/price)"/> 

to return the sum of all items' prices, regardless of their placement in the input XML's hierarchy.

If, for some reason, you wanted to use recursion, then it might be done as:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <total>
        <xsl:call-template name="sumPrices">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="//item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sumPrices">
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$items">
            <xsl:variable name="currentPrice" select="$items[1]/price"/>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="sumPrices">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $currentPrice"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But again, there is no reason to do it.

OP: In procedural programming, traversing parent-child hierarchies via recursion naturally aligns the language call stack with the data hierarchy.   It's possible to write procedure code in XSLT, but it's more natural to use declarative, XPath-based pattern matching over hierarchical data.   This answer nicely contrasts the difference between the two approaches in XSLT.   Go with pattern matching against the input data; it's the way to leverage XSLT's strength.
